# How can I extract the cosine transform formula used for 2D by scipy.fft.dct?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

For the 1D cosine transform the documentation is clear in [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.dct.html), and I can reproduce it easily:

The formula is:

[image: screenshot from scipy.fft.dct documentation detailing Type II DCT]

and here it is reproduced manually, for example for the third harmonic:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft, dct

y = np.array([10,3,5])

# dct() call:
print(dct(y, 2))

# manual reproduction for k = 2:
N = 3
k = 2
n = np.array([0,1,2])
2 * (
    y[0] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[0]+1))/(2*N)) + 
    y[1] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[1]+1))/(2*N)) + 
    y[2] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[2]+1))/(2*N)))
```

in both cases I get 9.

But there is no documentation for the 2D DCT, and my attempts at hacking the formula with a toy matrix are not working out:

Compare:

```
z = np.array([[ 2,  3       ],
             [ 10, 15]])
dct(z, axis=0)  # dct() call
```

to for instance:

```
N = 2
M = 2
k = 0
l = 0
n = np.array([0,1])
m = np.array([0,1])
M*N * (
    z[0,0] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[0]+1))/(2*N)) * np.cos((np.pi*l*(2*m[0]+1))/(2*M)) + 
    z[0,1] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[0]+1))/(2*N)) * np.cos((np.pi*l*(2*m[1]+1))/(2*M)) +
    z[1,0] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[1]+1))/(2*N)) * np.cos((np.pi*l*(2*m[0]+1))/(2*M)) +
    z[1,1] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[1]+1))/(2*N)) * np.cos((np.pi*l*(2*m[1]+1))/(2*M))
)
```

for the first coefficient.

Can anyone help me reconcile the output of `dct()` with my attempted manual calculation?

I guess the formula is not...

[image: screenshot of a generalized 2d DCT formula, crossed out with a red line]

but it would be really easy to correct if I could get the same output manually for one of the coefficients on the example matrix above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find the formula for the multidimensional mode because the function doesn't do multidimensional cosine transforms. The `axis` keyword should be suspicious: in NumPy, SciPy it typically determines the direction along which lower-dimensional operations should be performed.

In other words, `dct(z, axis=0)` is just a columnwise 1d cosine transform:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import dct

z = np.array([[ 2,  3],
             [ 10, 15]])
print(dct(z, axis=0))  # dct() call
print(np.array([dct(column) for column in z.T]).T)
# both outputs
# [[ 24.          36.        ]
#  [-11.3137085  -16.97056275]]
```

Note the two transposes on the last line: all that it did was first loop over the array to slice it according to columns, then join them again columnwise. The latter would probably be better spelled out as

```py
res = np.stack([dct(column) for column in z.T], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My motivation for the question is to eventually understand what is being done in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/311357/311006) with the inverse of the cosine transform using this function. I don't know if you could shed some light on it...

Comment: If I understand your answer properly, the dct() call just does a 1D cosine transform for each column independently, which explains the output in matrix form.

Comment: @Mathtourist Yes, `dct` just does a 1d cosine transform over columns (or rows, depending on `axis`) for a 2d array. The linked answer calls `idct` twice! That's how it implements a 2d `idct`.

Comment: One last question, if I may, would the equation in the last part of the original post be correct, then (doing it twice)?

Comment: @Mathtourist No, I think the correct formula has to use a 2d array. So in the sum you have `x_{nm}` (instead of `x_n y_m`), but the rest of the formula is probably correct. If you pull out one of the factors of 2 and one of the sums, you should see the formula reflecting `dct(dct(z, axis=0), axis=1)` or something along those lines. The formula should be very transparent in this regard. Let me know if I didn't explain it clearly enough.

Comment: I got it working with 4 as the "normalizing" factor, using `dct(dct(z.T, axis=0).T, axis=0)`. Do you think it is correct, in light of this discussion, to apply `dct()` only once to the identity matrix and get the discrete cosine transform matrix as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876150/15183594)?

Comment: I would, in particular, expect identical results applied to the identity if I did apply it twice, as though it was a regular matrix as in the example above, but this is not the case: `dct(dct(np.eye(4).T, axis=0).T, axis=0)` is different to `dct(np.eye(4), axis=0)`. So in the answer to my prior comment the DCT matrix is different than if calculated applying `dct()` twice as in the post in crossvalidated... Isn't that surprising? I presume then that something is wrong with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876150/15183594). They probably used the function incorrectly?

Comment: @Mathtourist OK, but that's just a verbose way of doing `dct(dct(z, axis=1), axis=0)` ;) If I understand correctly the idea behind the matrix is to turn the `dct` call into a matrix multiplication: from `x_j` you go to `y_i` with `M_{ij} x_j`. This doesn't generalize to the 2d case: you can't (easily?) transform both indices with a single matrix product. You could, however, multiply by the same matrix twice: take `M = dct(np.eye(z.shape[0]), axis=0)` and then `dct(dct(z, axis=1), axis=0)` should be the same as `M @ z @ M.T`.

Comment: In other words, to define a "matrix" (tensor, linear transformation) that does the 2d DCT for you you'd need a _four-index_ quantity that can be applied to the indices of the original array.